# slurm - independent tasks run slowly when all in one job

Tags: fortran, cluster-computing, slurm, sbatch

I'm calculating power spectra (Fourier transforms) of astronomical time series data. I have ~6,000 time series data sets, which naturally parallelizes. For my data I already calculated power spectra for all data sets up to a certain frequency. I now want to go to higher frequencies, and so I'm dividing the power spectrum calculations into sections to avoid going over the 24 hour limit for long jobs.

On individual non-cluster machines, my code runs in parallel with no slow downs, as long as I keep to less than the number of cores. However, on the cluster I find that the individual calculations run more slowly depending on how many CPUs I'm using in each job. If I have a couple of jobs running, they don't seem to impact each other - it seems somehow the tasks within a single job are causing the slow down. But if I split everything into small jobs, I then run into the limit on submitted jobs on our system. In addition, I can't exploit the full potential of our system. We can use up to 6,300 CPUs, but the job limit is 25.

My power spectrum code is written in Fortran (yes, old school!) and my slurm tasks look like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/csh
    #To run this type: sbatch calculate_power_A2.sh
    #SBATCH --time=11:59:00
    #SBATCH -o calculate_power_A2.out
    #SBATCH -e calculate_power_A2.err
    #SBATCH --ntasks=400
    #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=25
    cd [...]/Powtest9
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0427.8-6704_1&
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0427.8-6704_2&
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0427.8-6704_3&
    ...
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0427.8-6704_80&
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0000.3-7355_1&
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0000.3-7355_2&
    ...
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0000.3-7355_79&
    pow pow_drive.4FGLJ0000.3-7355_80&
    wait
```

"pow" is my compiled Fortran code
size ~/bin/pow
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
26356     856 352073336   352100548   14fca0c4

The command line arguments are small files that specify the data set to read, the frequency range to calculate, and the output file to write to.
The "4FGLJ0427.8-6704" part relates to the data set to read.
What I find is that the time taken for the job seems to scale with the number of data sets that I'm performing calculations on. I can't figure out why that seems to be happening, as the tasks are split over multiple nodes, and the calculations should be completely independent.
I'm doing I/O only at the start to read in the data set, and that takes less than a minute, and to write out the data at the end, which is also rather short.

Any suggestions on what I could do to get the tasks not slowing each other down would be very appreciated!

I tried reducing the number of tasks per node, but it wasn't clear that helped much.
I experimented with the number of data sets being analyzed in total - in principle I don't think that should affect the speed, but instead the time taken seemed to scale with the number of independent input data sets.

Comment: Are you *sure* the jobs are starting on different nodes? What does it tell you if (assuming a Unix-like system) you `Call execute_command_line( "hostname" )` in your Fortran program?

Comment: Does your code use a library such as BLAS or LAPACK that might be multithreaded?

Comment: There are no libraries being used, apart from /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0. 
squeue shows different nodes being assigned.

Comment: Different nodes might be assigned to the job, but are you *sure* that the executables you run start on different nodes? Normally you would have to do something "special" to start an executable on a remote node from that upon which the batch script is running

Comment: Surely that's what sbatch does. I'm certainly not running on a login node.

Comment: I agree with Ian Bush, I think all your processes are running on a single node. sbatch just allocates nodes to the job, it does not launch the processes on multiple nodes. You probably need to prefix all your commands with a command to launch on different nodes, e.g. "srun --ntasks=1 --ntasks-per-node=1 pow ... &". Other commands/options may be needed as it depends on how Slurm is configured on the system you are using.

Comment: How exactly slower are the jobs running? 10% 4x? It is not clear from your description.

Comment: The jobs will indeed run on a single node. Not the login node, but only one execute node for all 400 processes running all concurrently. I suggest trying an interactive job and observing what is happenning using `top` and pressing 1 inside top. You could also try `mpirun -n 1 process1 : -n 1 process2 : ...` (or a slurm equivalent).

Comment: Sbatch just requests resources. It's up to you how you use them. It certainly by default does nothing for job placement.

Comment: The simplet way to do what you want to do in Slurm is probably via a job array https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html - submit an array of 1 node jobs, this will mean your groups of 25 processes will all start on different nodes.

Comment: The tasks are definitely _not_ running on a single node. For a different analysis I was using some software package that was very memory intensive and the systems people reported nodes were running out of memory. That was resolved using the --ntasks-per-node specification, as above. squeue also shows the number of nodes allocated, and when the job is running it specifically shows which nodes are being used.

Comment: e.g.   
$ squeue | grep henry  
          19032723   compute calculat  henry  R      48:53      4 borgh[008-011]  
          19033754   compute calculat  henry  R      48:53     16 borgi[005-020]

Answer (score 0):

Your submission script does not contain the logic to dispatch the processes to the allocated resources. Everything runs on the first node of the allocation. You need to prefix all your `pow` lines with `srun --exact -n 1`

See more information in the `srun` manpage

- https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_Example-7:
- https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_exact

Comment: No, as explained above, the tasks pretty clearly are running on multiple nodes. I can see the number of nodes change as I change ntasks-per-node.

Comment: And, I get a slowdown even if the number of tasks easily fits into one node.

Comment: I believe you that the number of nodes change as you change ntasks-per-node. But that does not mean the job is distributed among those nodes. It merely means resources are reserved there. You should check the load of the nodes to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. It appears I was confused about what was happening!